# How can I configure Sitecore search to retrieve custom values from the search index

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore

I am using the AdvancedDatabaseCrawler as a base for my search page. I have configured it so that I can search for what I want and it is very fast. The problem is that as soon as you want to do anything with the search results that requires accessing field values the performance goes through the roof.

The main search results part is fine as even if there are 1000 results returned from the search I am only showing 10 or 20 results per page which means I only have to retrieve 10 or 20 items. However in the sidebar I am listing out various filtering options with the number or results associated with each filtering option (eBay style). In order to retrieve these filter options I perform a relationship search based on the search results. Since the search results only contain SkinnyItems it has to call GetItem() on every single result to get the actual item in order to get the value that I'm filtering by. In other words it will call Database.GetItem(id) 1000 times! Obviously that is not terribly efficient.

Am I missing something here? Is there any way to configure Sitecore search to retrieve custom values from the search index? If I can search for the values in the index why can't I also retrieve them? If I can't, how else can I process the results without getting each individual item from the database?

Here is an idea of the functionality that I’m after: http://cameras.shop.ebay.com.au/Digital-Cameras-/31388/i.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've currently resolved this by defining dynamic fields for every field that I will need to filter by or return in the search result collection. That way I can achieve the facetted searching that is required without needing to grab field values from the database. I'm assuming that by adding the dynamic fields we are taking a performance hit when rebuilding the index. But I can live with that.

In the future we'll probably look at utilizing a product like Apache Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Klaus answered on SDN: use facetting with Apache Solr or similar.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=35618